# Dynamic GridView and float formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I create a GridView from code and bind it to data like this:

```
GridView myGridView1 = new GridView();
myGridView1.DataSource = db.T_Values.Select(x => new 
    {
        x.TimeStamp, 
        x.Value, 
        x.Type
    }).OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp).ToList();
myGridView1.DataBind();
```

If the value is like 0,00000000123123 then GridView rounds this number. Is it possible to avoid that and display the full number?

Comment: Did you try `x.Value.ToString()`?

Comment: this is entity, i can't do it, or i can? but just toString will crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe for gridview event OnRowDataBound. In this event you have make that value a string and assign it to some column instead of auto generate column if problem not solved

Comment: no , you r wrong, when you create gridview dynamically , then even if u catch this event , columns count is alwyas = 0

Comment: If gridview is generated dynamically I think we have to add columns to it dynamically instead of auto generating column as I said in my answer before. Do you have any requirement to created grid dynamically on server side. @kosnkov solution might be better in your situation

Answer (score 0):

M.Babcock helped, it is enought to first do ToList() and then Value = x.Value.toString("0,0000000000")